# php file_get_contents working but need to set URL paths to CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['orderid'])){
    echo file_get_contents("http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/PODLookupResults.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATEGUID=7ca82b1d-b722-4cdc-b74a-b338d8577ffa&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAevVXD1oYELeveMr0vHCmYPaomE%2FDwQD43eOdzEj3p%2Fm4U4pgxq6tlupSJfQZQBazFFj%2F1LmlGLyHFagz1yHZm8bjowVgAJ8C3e%2B2bVMPt91KjXCHjnAsonQDi2zFSuasUVzpitHiLDCDtiLHCjNCQG4CxrbV5VPFqBeOgs2X52AD%2FEb%2BYR%2BEJ68PaN2CiyKzE%3D&ctl00%24ctl16%24tbHeaderSearch=Search..&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbAccountRef=01484267&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbConsignmentRef=".$_GET['orderid']."&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbDestPostcode=".$_GET['postcode']."&ctl00%24maincontent%24btnDoPODLookup=Search+Again");
}
```

Which once I have working will use AJAX to pull it from here but testing it, I think I also need to set the paths to the JS and CSS files it pulls through but all are like /Scripts/ /css/ etc... is there any way to apply in front of them tuffnells.co.uk/ as I don't think the page is working as the js is not loading up.

The page looks like the default form and its not passing and showing the tracking data like it does when I use this url

`http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/PODLookupResults.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATEGUID=7ca82b1d-b722-4cdc-b74a-b338d8577ffa&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAevVXD1oYELeveMr0vHCmYPaomE%2FDwQD43eOdzEj3p%2Fm4U4pgxq6tlupSJfQZQBazFFj%2F1LmlGLyHFagz1yHZm8bjowVgAJ8C3e%2B2bVMPt91KjXCHjnAsonQDi2zFSuasUVzpitHiLDCDtiLHCjNCQG4CxrbV5VPFqBeOgs2X52AD%2FEb%2BYR%2BEJ68PaN2CiyKzE%3D&ctl00%24ctl16%24tbHeaderSearch=Search..&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbAccountRef=01484267&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbConsignmentRef=2837&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbDestPostcode=AL15BY&ctl00%24maincontent%24btnDoPODLookup=Search+Again`

Which is the URL im using for the file_get_contents... any ideas?

The JS so far that I will want to use is this, is this right as well?

```
<div id="tracking"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var orderid = "2837";
    var postcode = "AL15BY";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.ambientlounge.com/external/ukTracking.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            orderid: orderid,
            postcode: postcode
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#tracking').html($(data).find('#ctl00_maincontent_pnlPODRecords').html());
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm wanting to get the page data, then return to the AJAX ideally to display on one of our pages, just the `#ctl00_maincontent_pnlPODRecords` div and its contents.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but if you want to make sure all relative links still work, you can try inserting a [`<base`>](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) url in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Try to get the file_get_contents into a variable and then replace the src and href values by appending the full path. You can do that by regex. Then when finally done then you can echo the whole string with the replaced full paths.

Comment: use google chrome, right click, inspect element these tools will be your friend. go to console to see if you have any errors

Comment: Lots of 404 errors, im just thinking that is its not showing the tracking but the form even though im posting the same url. if you click the full url above your see tracking and the ukTracking.php one i made it shows the form - im assuming its because 404 on the js maybe i dont know. Im new to PHP do you know how i could use regex to fix that to see? ill give base a go as well.

Comment: Ahh base worked fine, its just showing the form though so maybe its not posting correctly.. as want it to auto load straight to the details

Comment: Ahh just trying something, think something to do with the session control that end